# How to add keydown event in element-ui table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I did not find `keydown event` in Table Methods. I tried to add

```
@keydown.native="test"
```

in a table but is doesn't work.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: are you using datatables?

Comment: im using element-ui <el-table> component. i did not find keydown event for el-table http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Comment: Why do you need keydown for a table? Don't you need rather keydown for an input inside the table? There is no keydown element in the docs because these are not JS events but table-specific events (so e. g. not a regular click but a click on a row or a cell) and native doesn't work because the keydown event is not for a table, it is for inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Here, my req is to monitor Shift keydown event, to implement batch rows selection in a table. That's why I wanna find keydown event for table. However, el-table has not the event. So, I find we need to implement it in the document element.

```
created:function(){
  document.onkeydown=function(e){
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    if(key==16){
      alert('Shift down')
    }
  }
  document.onkeyup=function(e){
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    if(key==13){
      alert('Enter up')
    }
  }
},
```